# Flot pie chart gives error in firebug: "uncaught exception: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null"

Tags: jquery, charts, pie-chart

I using [flot](https://github.com/flot/flot) pie chart for plotting pie charts. but it shows error in firebug that

> uncaught exception: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height
>   = null

I have given the height and width from stylesheet also. and tried also like this

`<div id="placeholder1" style="width:140px;height:140px" ></div>`

how to resolve this?

Comment: Check that you placed your code within `$(document).ready()` handler.

Comment: the code is within $(document).ready() handler. but result is same

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check these:

- You include the jQuery library first and then flot js library
- Wrap the whole code within `$(document).ready()` handler function.
- you bind the flot with correct `id` and there is no repeat of same `id`.
- if your `div` is dynamic i.e. appeared to DOM after page load then bind `plot()` after 
  the element appeared to DOM.

Comment: I check all these , but result is same.

Comment: In my case the <script> tag appeared before the div container. After moving it past the container, it works correctly

Comment: also, check all references in JS to make sure you are calling existing DIV id.  In my case there was more than one call to the DIV, and I missed it thinking there was only one.

Comment: You need to re-fetch the DOM element for your chart. It gets changed by flot when you call $.plot. i.e. do something like this: $.plot($("#myChart"), data, options);

Comment: Bullet #3 (ID related) happens more than expected...thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I also had the same problem. I set a height and a width to the `<div>` tag and it fixed the error.

You can use either inline css (as I did) or JS to set the height and the width. But `plot()` function should be called only after we set the height of the `<div>`

```
<div class="bars_two" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem too! The answer was not listed above, so here was my problem and solution.

```
<div id="chart" class="chart" style="width:100%;height:250px;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [...];
        var options = {...};
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
    });
</script>
```

So. Notice the plot function. At first, I didn't have the # in the first parameter. That is necessary apparently. It solved my problems.

GG.

Answer (score 7):

A quick solution I found is to just type something between the div tags.
For example:
Change
`<div id="placeholder"></div>`
to
`<div id="placeholder">.</div>` or `<div id="placeholder">randomtext</div>`.

Personally, I found that using space/tabs/newlines doesn't work in this quick solution.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I got a period, my graph outline, and the same indexsize error

Answer (score 3):

If you put your chart html in div which is given "display: none" class you will get this error. You must put your chart html in div which is given "display:block" class when "jquery.flot.js" is loaded.

```
<div id="pie_chart" class="chart"> </div>
```

if this html is in any div which has `class="display: none"` when "jquery.flot.js" is loaded, change it to `display: block`

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.   If this is true, How can I include the script once at the head section of the page, and then generate charts on the fly with ajax?

Comment: this is brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem integrating template to rails. That's a bad way, but I just comment the line which throws the exception and add 2 lines to set width and height to 0 - it helped me.

```
Canvas.prototype.resize = function(width, height) {

  if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
    // COMMENTED NEXT LINE
    // throw new Error("Invalid dimensions for plot, width = " + width + ", height = " + height);
    // NEW LINES ADDED
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
  }

  // ... others code 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that before you render to a chart, you need to re-fetch the DOM element. Since flot manipulates the elements and inserts its own, it looks like it's replacing the element with its own elements.

In your render, do:

```
$.plot($(".myChartId || #myChartClass"), myData, myOptions);
```

This has nothing to do with being in `$(document).ready()`, although it is good practice to place it inside of this.

Hope this helps!